# Is there a python module that convert a value and an error to a scientific notation?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-notation

Suppose I have two numbers, `v = 0.01342` and `err = 0.0004`. Under scientific notation, this would be written as `(13.4 ± 0.4)e-3`. Is there a function that does that conversion (probably on scipy)? Naturally, the important thing is the numbers and not the `±` sign. Searching the web, I learned that there is (are?) function(s?) which eat a number to transform and a number of desired digit and they spit the result. This is not what I'm searching for.  I've written once but it turned out to be quite ugly.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand what you meant by the last few lines, but when you have a specific output like yours, you usually have to write you own.

```
def sci_not(v,err,rnd=1):
    power = - int(('%E' % v)[-3:])+1
    return '({0} +/- {1})e{2}'.format(
            round(v*10**power,rnd),round(err*10**power,rnd),power)
```

This does the trick

```
>>> v = .01342
>>> err = .0004
>>> sci_not(v,err)
(13.4 +/- 0.4)e3
```

**EDIT :** You can put in the ± character if you make the string unicode, but the results only look pretty when you use a print statment.

Replace the previous return statement with

```
return u'({0} \u00B1 {1})e{2}'.format(
            round(v*10**power,rnd),round(err*10**power,rnd),power)
```

This returns

```
>>> sci_not(v,err)
u'(13.4 \xb1 0.4)e3'
>>> print sci_not(v,err)
(13.4 ± 0.4)e3
```

Comment: It is not so simple. If error value starts with 1 then the `err` is to be rounded to two digits. After the err is rounded one knows to how many digits to round the value. If I have v = 235.3654, and err= 0.143, from `sci_not` I get (23.5 +/- 0.0)e-1 instead of (23.537 +/- 1.4)e1. The variable `pov` should be estimated from `err`, plus the rest of code needs correction accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can display numbers in scientific notation using [.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
v = 0.01342
err = 0.0004

print ('({:.2e}'.format(float(v)) + ' +/- ' + '{:.2e}'.format(float(err)) + ')')
```

Will output the following:

```
(1.34e-02 +/- 4.00e-04)
```

the .2 of {:.2e} specifies the precision, which prevents any overly ugly numbers

Comment: The goal is to calculate the ``2`` in the ``{:.2e}`` via the function. There are about 80 of those I need to do.